# Rails: Get only certain attributes of submodel with method 'attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to get only certain fields of a foreign model like this:

```
@user = User.find(:first, :select => ['`users`.`id`, `users`.`nickname`, `users`.`birthdate`, `users`.`sex`'], :conditions => ['`users`.`id` = ?', id])

city = @user.profile.city.attributes
```

With `attributes` I retrieve all attributes of my city model. I'd like to get only some. Something like:

```
city = @user.profile.city.attributes[:name, :postcode]
```

Is it possible by keeping the syntax as simple as above? I want to use `attributes` to receive a Hash.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if you don't mind that it picks out fields after the SQL returns everything:

```
@user.profile.city.attributes.select{|k,v| ["name","postcode"].include?(k)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to select fields of foreign models when chaining in the way you have. The only way would be to do a query on the City model:

```
City.where(:profile_id => @user.profile.id, :select => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give arguements after attributes otherwise it will raise ArguementError. In this case you can use inner join to fetch the records.

Answer (score 0):

```
city = @user.profile.city.pluck(:name, :postcode)
```